# Socket.io client API, is connecting synchronous?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, websocket, socket.io

When I have the following code:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
```

Does the io function returns the socket synchronous?

I currently have it wrapped in a Promise like this (typescript btw):

```
  public getSocket (): Promise<any> {

    if (!this.socketPromise) {
        this.socketPromise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
            res(io('http://localhost:3000'));
        });
    }
    return this.socketPromise;
  }
```

But this wrapping in a Promise would not be needed if the io method returns synchronously.

Comment: Wrapping it like that won't help at all if it *doesn't* return synchronously!

Comment: It's synchronous.

Comment: Thanks, I feel really stupid now